# Service Fabric Local Cluster "unable to route request to..." - After upgrading Windows 10 May 2019

Tags: c#, windows, azure-service-fabric

Upgraded Windows 10 today. PC restarted and had to start my local cluster again. Now I receive a 502 code and "Unable to route request to... ". There are no exceptions thrown in the cluster gateway and the service appears to be receiving requests despite not making it into the controller.

Has anyone else experienced Service Fabric issues after this May 2019 Windows update?

Comment: did you try reinstalling the sdk?

Comment: As the above comment mentions, you likely need to reinstall the SDK